# What size does of stack does java -xss16M allocate 16 MegaBytes or 16Megabits

Tags: java, jvm, tail-recursion, factorial

I am attempting to prove that I am using tail recursion properly by restricting the size allocated to the thread stack using the java -Xss160M command. I am writing a simple tail recursion algorithm for finding the factorial of a really big numbers:

```
/*
*
*my Program
*
*/

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class TailFactorial {
private BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n, BigInteger acc) {
    if (n.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) return acc;
    else return factorial(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), n.multiply(acc));
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TailFactorial classs = new TailFactorial();
    int num;
    BigInteger bigNum = BigInteger.ONE;
    boolean gTG = false;
    String finalNumString = "";
    String msg = "";
    try {
        num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        bigNum = BigInteger.valueOf(num);
        msg = "fact("+String.valueOf(num)+") = ";
        gTG = true;

    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not get arguments, please make sure you are passing an integer");
        gTG = false;
    }
    try {
        if(gTG) {
            BigInteger finalNum = classs.factorial(bigNum ,BigInteger.ONE);
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(finalNum.bitCount()));
            finalNumString = finalNum.toString();
            //System.out.println( msg + finalNumString);
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("Exiting");
        }

    }catch(StackOverflowError e) {
        System.out.print("Not enough memory allocated to stack, try exicuting with java -Xss$bigger memory inserted here$ TrailFactorial");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Unrecoginzed error in finding factorial");
    }



}

}
```

The code runs just fine, but I have to allocate 50M to the stack. When I run the current program, it displays the bit count of the result. When I find the factorial of one-hundred-thousand the bit count is 708,218, and I still have to use 50M. Can someone explain to me the meaning of the M? is it megabytes or bits? Am I not implementing tail-recursion properly?

Comment: `BigInteger` objects are not allocated on the stack. Stack is used for recursive calls. There is no correlation between bit count and required stack size. And you cannot prove tail-recursion, because **Java doesn't implement tail-recursion**, which is why you need large stack. As for your question, `M` is in bytes.

Comment: It is megabytes.  Read the documentation for the `java` command line options.

Comment: If this is the case, why can I run TailFactorial of 100 with the argument -Xss228k? For some reason it is ending up on the stack because larger factorials require larger stack sizes.

Comment: Larger factorials require larger stacks, because it performs more recursions.

Comment: Thanks Stephen C! Thats what I was looking for!

Comment: Andrea-  does that mean that my tail-recursion is not working, I mean after all, tail recursion is to prevent there from being a large stack size. There should be no stacks with tail tail recursion. I should be able to interrupt the process at any given moment and see a partial answer, unlike pure recursion

Comment: Read my first comment again: **Java doesn't implement tail-recursion**. See [Why doesn't Java have optimization for tail-recursion at all?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/272061/202153)

Comment: @MorrisSowards - OK ... but you should have looked at the documentation first.  It saves everyone's time if you do that.

Comment: Oh, damn. I understand now, sorry that helps alot.

Comment: You're using numerology to understand the problem

Comment: The native stack uses virtual memory which is only allocated when touched. If you have a 64-bit VM, and you don't use all the stack it hardly matters.

Comment: As `n` is limited to the size of an `int` for a host of reasons, there is no point making it a `BigInteger` except for the purposes of multiplying with the accumulator.

Comment: You don't need to be `restricting the size ... of the stack` It's always restricted, so for a large enough `n` it will always fail.

Answer (score 2):

As noted; Java doesn't support tail call recursion optimisation so for a large `n` value you will always run out of stack.

I suggest you use a simple loop if you want to avoid this.

```
public static BigInteger factorial(int n) {
    BigInteger acc = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        acc = acc.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    return acc;
}
```

If you **really, really** want to use recursion, you can use divide and conquer

```
public static BigInteger factorial(int n) {
    return product(1, n);
}

public static BigInteger product(int from, int to) {
    if (from == to) return BigInteger.valueOf(from);
    int mid = (from + to) >>> 1;
    return product(from, mid).multiply(product(mid + 1, to));
}
```

This has a stack depth of `log2(n)` or a maximum of ~32.

BTW The following code

```
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(finalNum.bitCount()));
        finalNumString = finalNum.toString();
        System.out.println( msg + finalNumString);
```

is the same as

```
        System.out.println(finalNum.bitCount());
        System.out.println(msg + finalNum);
```

Comment: BTW divide and conquer is one of most efficient ways to calculate factorial with 'BigInteger',  just cycling from 1 to N is much slower.

Comment: Divide and conquer is nice idea, though the naming is little bit confusing. I would rename the `factorial(int from, int to)` method to `product(int from, int to)`.